# ERROR - WSO2 with rabbitMQ

Tags: rabbitmq, wso2, wso2-esb

In proxy i have this to send to rabbitMQ:

```html
         <property name="messageType" value="text/xml" scope="default"/>
         <property name="contentType" value="text/xml" scope="default"/>
         <property name="rabbitmq.attributes.app.id"
                   value="RMIS"
                   scope="axis2"
                   type="STRING"/>
         <property name="rabbitmq.attributes.type"
                   value="BRANCH"
                   scope="axis2"
                   type="STRING"/>
         <property name="rabbitmq.attributes.user.id"
                   value="RMIS"
                   scope="axis2"
                   type="STRING"/>
         <property name="MESSAGE_ID" expression="get-property('MessageID')"/>
         <script language="js">var messageID = mc.getProperty('MESSAGE_ID').substring(9,45);
          mc.setProperty("RABBIT_MESSAGE_ID", messageID);</script>
         <property name="rabbitmq.attributes.custom.message.id"
                   expression="get-property('RABBIT_MESSAGE_ID')"
                   scope="axis2"/>
         <clone continueParent="true">
            <target sequence="writeToFile"/>
         </clone>
         <send>
            <endpoint key="rabbit"/>
         </send>
```

in ENDPOINT:

```html
<endpoint xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="rabbit">
   <address uri="rabbitmq://writeToQueue?rabbitmq.server.host.name=localhost&rabbitmq.server.port=5672&rabbitmq.server.user.name=guest&rabbitmq.server.password=guest&rabbitmq.queue.name=queque" format="soap11">
      <suspendOnFailure>
         <progressionFactor>1.0</progressionFactor>
      </suspendOnFailure>
      <markForSuspension>
         <retriesBeforeSuspension>0</retriesBeforeSuspension>
         <retryDelay>3000</retryDelay>
      </markForSuspension>
      <timeout>
         <responseAction>fault</responseAction>
      </timeout>
   </address>
</endpoint>
```

but I catch an error, when i send it to rabbitMQ  Server:

```
TID[-1234] [ESB] [2016-06-03 16:32:06,479] ERROR {org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2Sender} - Unexpected error during sending message out
org.apache.axis2.transport.rabbitmq.RabbitMQMessage.(RabbitMQMessage.java:43)
org.apache.axis2.transport.rabbitmq.RabbitMQSender.sendOverAMQP(RabbitMQSender.java:84)
org.apache.axis2.transport.rabbitmq.RabbitMQSender.sendMessage(RabbitMQSender.java:72)
org.apache.axis2.transport.base.AbstractTransportSender.invoke(AbstractTransportSender.java:112)
org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.send(AxisEngine.java:442)
org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.DynamicAxisOperation$DynamicOperationClient.send(DynamicAxisOperation.java:185)
org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.DynamicAxisOperation$DynamicOperationClient.executeImpl(DynamicAxisOperation.java:167)
org.apache.axis2.client.OperationClient.execute(OperationClient.java:149)
org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2FlexibleMEPClient.send(Axis2FlexibleMEPClient.java:542)
org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2Sender.sendOn(Axis2Sender.java:79)
org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2SynapseEnvironment.send(Axis2SynapseEnvironment.java:461)
org.apache.synapse.endpoints.AbstractEndpoint.send(AbstractEndpoint.java:372)
org.apache.synapse.endpoints.AddressEndpoint.send(AddressEndpoint.java:65)
org.apache.synapse.endpoints.IndirectEndpoint.send(IndirectEndpoint.java:55)
org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.SendMediator.mediate(SendMediator.java:105)
org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:81)
org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:48)
org.apache.synapse.mediators.base.SequenceMediator.mediate(SequenceMediator.java:149)
org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.ProxyServiceMessageReceiver.receive(ProxyServiceMessageReceiver.java:185)
org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:180)
org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ServerWorker.processEntityEnclosingRequest(ServerWorker.java:395)
org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ServerWorker.run(ServerWorker.java:142)
org.apache.axis2.transport.base.threads.NativeWorkerPool$1.run(NativeWorkerPool.java:172)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

The log in WSO2 ESB there:
And i don't understand, why can not contact with rabbitMQ. In rabbitMQ also, i don't catch any error.
`ERROR_DETAIL : org.apache.synapse.SynapseException: Unexpected error during sending message out at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2Sender.handleException(Axis2Sender.java:247) at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2Sender.sendOn(Axis2Sender.java:91) at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2SynapseEnvironment.send(Axis2SynapseEnvironment.java:461) at org.apache.synapse.endpoints.AbstractEndpoint.send(AbstractEndpoint.java:372) at org.apache.synapse.endpoints.AddressEndpoint.send(AddressEndpoint.java:65) at org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.SendMediator.mediate(SendMediator.java:105) at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:81) at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:48) at org.apache.synapse.mediators.base.SequenceMediator.mediate(SequenceMediator.java:149) at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.ProxyServiceMessageReceiver.receive(ProxyServiceMessageReceiver.java:185) at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:180) at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ServerWorker.processEntityEnclosingRequest(ServerWorker.java:395) at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ServerWorker.run(ServerWorker.java:142) at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.threads.NativeWorkerPool$1.run(NativeWorkerPool.java:172) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException at org.apache.axis2.transport.rabbitmq.RabbitMQMessage.&lt;init&gt;(RabbitMQMessage.java:43) at org.apache.axis2.transport.rabbitmq.RabbitMQSender.sendOverAMQP(RabbitMQSender.java:84) at org.apache.axis2.transport.rabbitmq.RabbitMQSender.sendMessage(RabbitMQSender.java:72) at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.AbstractTransportSender.invoke(AbstractTransportSender.java:112) at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.send(AxisEngine.java:442) at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.DynamicAxisOperation$DynamicOperationClient.send(DynamicAxisOperation.java:185) at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.DynamicAxisOperation$DynamicOperationClient.executeImpl(DynamicAxisOperation.java:167) at org.apache.axis2.client.OperationClient.execute(OperationClient.java:149) at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2FlexibleMEPClient.send(Axis2FlexibleMEPClient.java:542) at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2Sender.sendOn(Axis2Sender.java:79) ... 15 more`

new stackTrace:
`[2016-06-27 17:07:00,380] ERROR - Axis2Sender Unexpected error during sending message out
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Invalid configuration: 'routingKey' must be non-null.
        at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQImpl$Basic$Publish.(AMQImpl.java:2278)
        at com.rabbitmq.client.AMQP$Basic$Publish$Builder.build(AMQP.java:1219)
        at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.ChannelN.basicPublish(ChannelN.java:647)
        at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.ChannelN.basicPublish(ChannelN.java:630)
        at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.ChannelN.basicPublish(ChannelN.java:621)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.rabbitmq.RabbitMQMessageSender.send(RabbitMQMessageSender.java:252)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.rabbitmq.RabbitMQSender.sendOverAMQP(RabbitMQSender.java:85)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.rabbitmq.RabbitMQSender.sendMessage(RabbitMQSender.java:72)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.AbstractTransportSender.invoke(AbstractTransportSender.java:112)
        at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.send(AxisEngine.java:442)
        at org.apache.axis2.description.OutOnlyAxisOperationClient.executeImpl(OutOnlyAxisOperation.java:297)
        at org.apache.axis2.client.OperationClient.execute(OperationClient.java:149)
        at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2FlexibleMEPClient.send(Axis2FlexibleMEPClient.java:542)
        at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2Sender.sendOn(Axis2Sender.java:79)
        at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2SynapseEnvironment.send(Axis2SynapseEnvironment.java:461)
        at org.apache.synapse.endpoints.AbstractEndpoint.send(AbstractEndpoint.java:372)
        at org.apache.synapse.endpoints.AddressEndpoint.send(AddressEndpoint.java:65)
        at org.apache.synapse.endpoints.IndirectEndpoint.send(IndirectEndpoint.java:55)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.SendMediator.mediate(SendMediator.java:105)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:81)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:48)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.base.SequenceMediator.mediate(SequenceMediator.java:149)
        at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.ProxyServiceMessageReceiver.receive(ProxyServiceMessageReceiver.java:185)
        at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:180)
        at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ServerWorker.processEntityEnclosingRequest(ServerWorker.java:395)
        at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ServerWorker.run(ServerWorker.java:142)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.threads.NativeWorkerPool$1.run(NativeWorkerPool.java:172)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
[2016-06-27 17:07:00,386]  WARN - FaultHandler ERROR_CODE : 0
[2016-06-27 17:07:00,386]  WARN - FaultHandler ERROR_MESSAGE : Unexpected error during sending message out
[2016-06-27 17:07:00,387]  WARN - FaultHandler ERROR_DETAIL : org.apache.synapse.SynapseException: Unexpected error during sending message out
        at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2Sender.handleException(Axis2Sender.java:247)
        at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2Sender.sendOn(Axis2Sender.java:91)
        at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2SynapseEnvironment.send(Axis2SynapseEnvironment.java:461)
        at org.apache.synapse.endpoints.AbstractEndpoint.send(AbstractEndpoint.java:372)
        at org.apache.synapse.endpoints.AddressEndpoint.send(AddressEndpoint.java:65)
        at org.apache.synapse.endpoints.IndirectEndpoint.send(IndirectEndpoint.java:55)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.SendMediator.mediate(SendMediator.java:105)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:81)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:48)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.base.SequenceMediator.mediate(SequenceMediator.java:149)
        at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.ProxyServiceMessageReceiver.receive(ProxyServiceMessageReceiver.java:185)
        at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:180)
        at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ServerWorker.processEntityEnclosingRequest(ServerWorker.java:395)
        at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ServerWorker.run(ServerWorker.java:142)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.threads.NativeWorkerPool$1.run(NativeWorkerPool.java:172)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Invalid configuration: 'routingKey' must be non-null.
        at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQImpl$Basic$Publish.(AMQImpl.java:2278)
        at com.rabbitmq.client.AMQP$Basic$Publish$Builder.build(AMQP.java:1219)
        at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.ChannelN.basicPublish(ChannelN.java:647)
        at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.ChannelN.basicPublish(ChannelN.java:630)
        at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.ChannelN.basicPublish(ChannelN.java:621)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.rabbitmq.RabbitMQMessageSender.send(RabbitMQMessageSender.java:252)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.rabbitmq.RabbitMQSender.sendOverAMQP(RabbitMQSender.java:85)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.rabbitmq.RabbitMQSender.sendMessage(RabbitMQSender.java:72)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.AbstractTransportSender.invoke(AbstractTransportSender.java:112)
        at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.send(AxisEngine.java:442)
        at org.apache.axis2.description.OutOnlyAxisOperationClient.executeImpl(OutOnlyAxisOperation.java:297)
        at org.apache.axis2.client.OperationClient.execute(OperationClient.java:149)
        at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2FlexibleMEPClient.send(Axis2FlexibleMEPClient.java:542)
        at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2Sender.sendOn(Axis2Sender.java:79)
        ... 16 more

[2016-06-27 17:07:00,388]  WARN - FaultHandler ERROR_EXCEPTION : org.apache.synapse.SynapseException: Unexpected error during sending message out
[2016-06-27 17:07:00,388]  WARN - FaultHandler FaultHandler : Endpoint [rabbit]
[2016-06-27 17:07:00,388]  WARN - EndpointContext Endpoint : rabbit will be marked SUSPENDED as it failed`

Comment: Is this the full stacktrace? It seems like the root exception is missing.

Comment: yes. It is full stacktrace from wso2  ESB UI

Comment: Pls check the log file in the file system, if you have access to. It might have more info in the logs.

Comment: Sorry. Its not the one I was looking for.

Comment: maybe this log? full stacktrace

Comment: maybe i worte wrong properties ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add following properties to insequence of Proxy.

```
<property name="OUT_ONLY" value="true"/>
<property name="FORCE_SC_ACCEPTED" value="true" scope="axis2"/>
```

Then your configurations should be like follow:

```
     <property name="messageType" value="text/xml" scope="default"/>
     <property name="contentType" value="text/xml" scope="default"/>
     <property name="OUT_ONLY" value="true"/>
     <property name="FORCE_SC_ACCEPTED" value="true" scope="axis2"/>
     <property name="rabbitmq.attributes.app.id"
               value="RMIS"
               scope="axis2"
               type="STRING"/>
     <property name="rabbitmq.attributes.type"
               value="BRANCH"
               scope="axis2"
               type="STRING"/>
     <property name="rabbitmq.attributes.user.id"
               value="RMIS"
               scope="axis2"
               type="STRING"/>
     <property name="MESSAGE_ID" expression="get-property('MessageID')"/>
     <script language="js">var messageID = mc.getProperty('MESSAGE_ID').substring(9,45);
        mc.setProperty("RABBIT_MESSAGE_ID", messageID);</script>
     <property name="rabbitmq.attributes.custom.message.id"
               expression="get-property('RABBIT_MESSAGE_ID')"
               scope="axis2"/>
     <clone continueParent="true">
        <target sequence="writeToFile"/>
     </clone>
     <send>
        <endpoint key="rabbit"/>
     </send>
```

According to new stackTrace, it is mention about "'routingKey' must be non-null."

Please add "rabbitmq.exchange.name" parameter and relevant value for that.

Ex:

```
<endpoint>
     <address
     uri="rabbitmq:/AMQPProxy?rabbitmq.server.host.name=192.168.0.3&rabbitmq.server.port=5672&rabbitmq.server.user.name=user&rabbitmq.server.password=abc123&rabbitmq.queue.name=queue2&rabbitmq.exchange.name=exchange2"/>
  </endpoint>
```

If you need further clarification, please refer WSO2 docs: https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB490/RabbitMQ+AMQP+Transport

Comment: a new statrace is above

Comment: I updated my answer. Please check on that. Update your configs accordingly.